# Is the difference between mono-runtime and mono-complete related to whether MySQL inserts successfully take place on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-connection

What is the difference between 1. `sudo apt-get install mono-runtime` and 2. `sudo apt-get purge --remove mono-complete` followed by `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` on an Ubuntu linux 16.04 instance?

I was told earlier today that the difference between mono-runtime and mono-complete could be related to whether MySQL inserts successfully take place in favor of mono-complete.

Another hypothesis is that the the difference between mono-runtime and mono-complete could be related to the Mono implementation of System.Windows.Forms.dll with respect to responding to button clicks or presses which start MySQL database manipulation operations(i.e. DML).

I have used strace before. So I could post snippets of strace output upon request.

In some quarters, sudo apt-get install mono-complete means install the Mono Rumtime environment. But that is not what I mean here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mono-complete`'s description is

> Mono is a platform for running and developing applications based on the
>    ECMA/ISO Standards. Mono is an open source effort led by Xamarin.
>    Mono provides a complete CLR (Common Language Runtime) including compiler and
>    runtime, which can produce and execute CIL (Common Intermediate Language)
>    bytecode (aka assemblies), and a class library.
>
> This is a metapackage and pulls in the Mono runtime, development tools and
>    all libraries.
>
> Install this package if you want to run software for Mono or Microsoft .NET
>    which you are not installing from a Debian package.

`mono-complete` pulls in `mono-runtime` and all the available Mono libraries, including whatever Mono libraries provide database support (including MySQL support presumably). So you'd expect database-using .NET software to work with `mono-complete`.

`mono-runtime` only contains the .NET VM and JIT and AOT code generators. If you only have that installed, not much .NET code will work, and database-using .NET software certainly won't.

Comment: After I installed  mono-runtime yesterday, I installed mysql-server, mysql-client , mysql-workbench and mysql dotnet connector 4.5 in cache for Ubuntu 16.04. Still, I observed that no MySQL database operations in mono ./BuildCameraList took place until we installed mono-complete. May I ask why that is? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a linux utility which traces: mono C# executable operation?

Comment: I imagine the MySQL database operations required `libmysql6.4-cil`, but I take it you've figured that out yourself ;-).

Comment: I found out that libmono-system-data4.0-cil for /usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Data.dll is also required in addition to libmysql6.4-cil.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to supplement Stephen Kitt's nice answer above for Ubuntu Linux 16.04:

1. monodis --assemblyref ./Target.exe (C#)
2. sudo apt install apt-file
3. apt-file update
4. for each assembly or DLL listed in step 1:

   For example, apt-file search MySQL.Data